# oAuth not authenticating on home server

Tags: linux, oauth, twitter-oauth

I set up a Twitter application that uses oAuth.
I am able to authenticate fine on an amazon ec2 centos server and it accepts my consumer keys and can see my application. But oAuth cannot on my home centos server. I am using Dyndns to make public my home server.

Maybe my home router is blocking the port oAuth uses. Maybe Dyndns is not allowing oAuth?

On my home server i enter in the consumer keys and click save and I get the error:
Unable to obtain OAuth tokens from Twitter. Please double-check the consumer key and secret are correct.

On Amazon ec2 I enter in the consumer keys and click save and I get"
Success! 'MYAPP' on Twitter has been added.

Comment: I was able to get oAuth to work by placing my ip on a DMZ

Answer (score 0):

Twitter implementation of OAuth uses HTTPS. So if your own server is OK with HTTPS, it should be OK for you too.